# Editable Data Grid tab out

Tags: wpf

I am working on WPF , editable data grid. I am having problem, when the user tabs out from the last cell of the grid, data grid is automatically creating new row. I want to restrict the data grid, as when a user tabs out, in code behind it check if current row was empty( no details were entered), then don't add a new row. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know  where you have problem but hope fuly this will help you ..there are properties of datagrid in xaml

```
<DataGrid Margin="22,187,-155,20" Name="DgStaffRoles" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
```